# Hit url against string but not responding

Tags: c#

I created the service called SMS serivice where i want to hit the url through the C# program
i use the following code for the same when i attach the service to the program and debug through it, I found that the code what i used is not hiting the borwser
My program :-

```
using System.Diagnostics;

string proc;

strUrlPath = "http://devices.panhealth.com/DeviceReading.aspx?Source=" + strSMS ";

proc= Process.Start("IExplore.exe",strUrlPath);
```

Still url is not hit.
but when this url copy past into IE it is working fine i want to hit it through program as following.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the System.Net.WebRequest class instead.

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://devices.panhealth.com/DeviceReading.aspx?Source=" + strSMS);
```

Answer (score 0):

just wonder...

```
string proc;
```

but

```
Process.Start
```

outputs a **Process** variable type.

---

from Object Browser info:

```
public static System.Diagnostics.Process Start(string fileName, string arguments)
Member of System.Diagnostics.Process
```

> **Summary**: Starts a process resource by
>   specifying the name of an application
>   and a set of command-line arguments,
>   and associates the resource with a new
>   System.Diagnostics.Process component.
>
> **Parameters**: fileName: The name of an
>   application file to run in the
>   process. arguments: Command-line
>   arguments to pass when starting the
>   process.
>
> **Returns**: A new
>   System.Diagnostics.Process component
>   that is associated with the process,
>   or null, if no process resource is
>   started (for example, if an existing
>   process is reused).

---

and, unless you have changed your **%PATH%** system variable to include the IE path, you need to use the full path

```
Process p;
p = Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe", "http://www.google.com/");
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Max - use either the WebRequest class. This has many advantages, not least because you can check the HTTP status code returned by the request to find out whether the request was successful.