# .net console app with hyperlinks?

Tags: c#, .net, console, console-application

is it possible ? any samples/patterns or ideas on how to go about it ?

Update -
this essentially becomes a text browser which displays various tables of information based on various commands on the prompt like typing the url in a browser

now instead of typing various commands like

prompt>command arg1 arg2
if only you could say "click" on the text in a certain "column"/"row" which would execute the command say

prompt>commandX arg1

it'd be somewhat faster/easier

Now, before someone mentions doing a typical browser/asp.net mvc/whatever app, i already have that running but have encountered some limitations esp. with accesing network files. etc. Now that's taken care of using a service-broker service which reads the file etc. but having added numerous extensions to it, it'd be somewhat easier if you could just run the app as a console prompt with a mvc pattern and add extensions to it etc. etc.

if only the text is clickable, it'd make it more friendly for use !!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The window's shell doesn't support clickable hyperlinks, so no, this isn't possible.

What are you trying to do that warrants the need for hyperlinks in the command shell?  Perhaps this application would be better built as a WinForms/WPF or ASP.NET application.

Comment: +1 for accuracy, although i wish the windows shell did support hyperlinks like it does in linux... it's useful sometimes

Comment: The "linux shell" doesn't support clickable hyperlinks. Your console smulator (Console, Terminal, KTerm, or whatever) does.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming no mouse, I would just launch the URL as a new process based on some keyboard trigger.

```
// this will launch the default browser    
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo("https://stackoverflow.com");
Process p = new Process(psi);
p.Start();
```

---

`VB` syntax:

```
// this will launch the default browser
Dim psi = New ProcessStartInfo("https://stackoverflow.com")
Dim p As Process = Process.Start(psi)
```

Comment: looks like the Q was not clear....the goal is to have clickable text in the console app

Comment: I don't think this code will work in .NET 4.5  Process() doesn't seem to take ProcessStartInfo as an argument any more.. you need to set it as a property.  I ended up actually doing the following:

Process.Start("IExplore.exe", show.ResultsURL);

Comment: @JayStevens:  Thanks for the info!  Some of those overloads for `Process.Start` in 4.5 are very nice!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what a "hyperlink" is for you, but in the context of a Console Application, you can have numbers or letters that you are expecting the user to press

(imagine a simple menu with 3 options)

```
Press one option

1 - Open ServerFault
2 - Open StackOverflow 
3 - Open SuperUser
```

and in the readline you have a switch that [start the IExplorer process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221552/hit-url-against-string-but-not-responding/1221579#1221579) for example and opens the webpage.

Is that what you call regarding "hyperlinks in a console application"?

Comment: I was hoping to somehow make certain text clikable/render with different color and then take different actions based on which text is clicked, akin to having a html table on a webpage and clicking on various column/rows executes different actions/url's etc.

Answer (score 1):

For an idea of what it can look like, get your hands on a copy of [links](http://links.sourceforge.net/).  It's a text-mode web browser that works just fine in several operating systems.

Comment: added more details above on why a browser is not sufficient here

Answer (score 0):

you can access the mouse from the console, if you wish to have clickable elements in your console application. you'll have to build the logic yourself of course for the clickable areas.

http://cboard.cprogramming.com/windows-programming/38680-win32-console-app-mouse-input.html