# How to make hyperlink in C# console application?

Tags: c#

I have problem. I making easy console to learn c# language. But i don't know how to make hyper link. I mean something like that:

```
System.Console.Write("Link"); //on click open https://www.google.pl/
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.net console app with hyperlinks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1246579/net-console-app-with-hyperlinks)

Comment: If using console interface is not an absolute requirement, you can achieve desired behavior when simulating console UI in a WinForms or WPF application. If you still want to use a console program, then you can implement your own console (with WinForms or WPF for example). Your own console will interpret the hyperlinks the way you want. Make others run your program through your own console.

Answer (score 0):

Many years late, but in case it helps anyone.
I believe it is not widely supported, but some terminal emulators allow you to use the sequence:

<kbd>ESC</kbd><kbd>]</kbd><kbd>8</kbd><kbd>;</kbd><kbd>;</kbd> *url* <kbd>ESC</kbd><kbd>\</kbd> text here

You unset it with the same sequence but empty

<kbd>ESC</kbd><kbd>]</kbd><kbd>8</kbd><kbd>;</kbd><kbd>;</kbd><kbd>ESC</kbd><kbd>\</kbd>

https://github.com/dotnet/msbuild/pull/8178