# How to make a text acting as a link in python

Tags: javascript, python, html, hyperlink

How to make a text acting as a link in python.
I am using pycharm which supports links so it is not a duplicate of [.net console app with hyperlinks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1246579/net-console-app-with-hyperlinks)
what i want to do is give a link and text to function(no problem if its more complicated than this) eg: i want to do

```
T = class.methodname(link,text)
print(T)
```

and if possible i want to able to copy this and still maintain its capabilities like

```
import pyperclip #this module allows #us to interact with the clipboard lyk
pyperclip.paste(T, copyastext=False, Retain_properties=True)#1st the T which is the first argument is same capital T from before 2nd of all i am just showing what i think it is like
```

this i think what should do is copy the text but acts as link **Just speculation**

The next things is js2py which i have a html and js example which is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
let text = "Free Web Building Tutorials!";
let result = text.link("https://www.w3schools.com");
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = result;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

js2py:python example

```
import js2py
Var=" The previous html file".replace("document","something")
print(js2py.eval_js(Var))
```

But i can't get this to work any help would be appreciated thanks in advance and my pc is windows 7 64bit